# Sort glossary: lower case before upper case

Tags: glossaries

Using [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), how can I sort the entries such that lower case characters appear before upper case characters?

The default behavior is just the other way round:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}
{
    name={a},
    description={lower case},
    sort={a}
}

\newglossaryentry{A}
{
    name={A},
    description={upper case},
    sort={A}
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall \printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'd like to have the entries sorted as follows: a, A, b, B, Cx, cy, Cy, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an automated method, use `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary`. In this case you don't have to specify the `sort` field since you have already the desired sorting. Also you don't have to run the `makeglossaries` program.

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}
{
    name={a},
    description={lower case},
}

\newglossaryentry{A}
{
    name={A},
    description={upper case},
}

\newglossaryentry{b}
{
    name={b},
    description={lower case},
}

\newglossaryentry{B}
{
    name={B},
    description={upper case},
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall \printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

If you don't like this method, since you are already using the `sort` field, you can simply invert `sort={A}` and `sort={a}` in the respective entries.

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}
{
    name={a},
    description={lower case},
    sort={A}
}

\newglossaryentry{A}
{
    name={A},
    description={upper case},
    sort={a}
}

\newglossaryentry{b}
{
    name={b},
    description={lower case},
    sort={B}
}

\newglossaryentry{B}
{
    name={B},
    description={upper case},
    sort={b}
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall \printglossary
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: This is, of course, one possibility. But I was hoping that there was a better way without the need to apply this "hack" directly to the sort key definitions as it leads to non-intuitive sort keys (which might be already complicated enough).

Comment: @Bloops Is the (now) first option not OK for you?

Comment: Maybe it is the easiest way to manually sort the list. But I think you are missing the `sort=def` option. Offtopic: The `nogroupskip` option seems to be incompatible with `\printnoidxglossary`, which troubled me for some time ...

Comment: @Bloops 1. If you set `sort=def` then you get your entries sorted in order of definition and not the way you've asked. 2. The option `nogroupskip` works perfectly for me, either as a package option or issued as `\printnoidxglossary[nogroupskip]`.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you meant by "since you have already the desired sorting". But anyway, the actual `name` fields contain a lot of complex mathematical symbols for which the plain tex sort mechanism (glossaries "option 1") does not work. Also I could not get it to work with the "alttree" style that I use in the actual script. So far, I ended up still using glossaries "option 2" (i.e., \makeglossaries) but with package option `sort=def` and manual sorting of the entries, which isn't so bad after all. But Thanks for inspiring me with your answer :)

Comment: @Bloops Glad to help.